# All children of class within parent with sibling

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have css which targets the child of a parent if the parent has a sibling of a certain class;

```
.sibling + .parent > [class^='child'] { style }
```

nav

```
-sibling
-parent
    -child1           <-- styled
    -child1           <-- styled
         -child2      <-- not styled
```

This works nicely for all the children on the first level, but I also want to target all grandchildren, greatgrandchildren etc etc

I don't want to use

```
.sibling + .parent > [class^='child'],
.sibling + .parent > [class^='child'] > [class^='child'],
.sibling + .parent > [class^='child'] > [class^='child'] > [class^='child'] { 
    style 
}
```

As this still only limits a few levels. How can I change this to be unlimited?

Comment: `.sibling + .parent + > [class^='child']` is an invalid selector.

Comment: Typos corrected, class names for illustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the descendant combinator is for — it targets descendants regardless of nesting level:

```
.sibling + .parent [class^='child']
```

(It is for this reason that "child" is a poor name for the elements you are targeting, but I'm going to assume it is just for illustration.)

Comment: You are correct, I fixed all three typos (long day...). Your solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Either specify the element `div` which will target the rest of the children divs:

```
.parent + .sibling > [class^='child'] div { style }
```

or use an asterisk `*` to target all children elements regardless of their tags.

```
.parent + .sibling > [class^='child'] * { style }
```